# WP-ADMIN - Listing all CPT in "posts" listing

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I am trying to show (back-end / wp-admin only) all posts and custom post types in one single place: ./wp-admin/edit.php

I am using this hook, in a custom mu-plugin:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function () {
global $typenow;

if( 'post' !== $typenow ) {
    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'any');
});
```

});

Code works fine, but:

a) I can't use `$query->set('post_type', ['post', 'my-cpt-1', 'my-cpt-2']);` because a warning: **( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in /app/public/wp-admin/edit.php on line 261**

b) Posts search (in wp-admin) doesn't works, it returns: **Invalid post type.** I think because **post_type** parameter is invalid, in query string.

Any idea to solve the issue?

Thank you